# Fiware Cygnus always wants to create a new MongoDB collection when it receives a notification

Tags: fiware, fiware-cygnus

I want to save historical data into MongoDB using Fiware Cygnus. But whenever Cygnus receives a notification it wants to create a new collection instead of adding a document if the collection already exists. I get this error message from Cygnus:

```
time=2017-01-14T20:58:11.785Z | lvl=WARN | corr=28eca6a8-da9c-11e6-841b-0242ac120009 | trans=9fa2d345-9aa1-4ff6-84df-75de5829a449 | srv=itg | subsrv=/building1 | comp=cygnus-ngsi | op=processNewBatches | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSISink[590] : Command failed with error 48: 'a collection 'sth_itg.sth_/building1_TemperatureRoom1_room' already exists' on server iot-mongo:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "a collection 'sth_itg.sth_/building1_TemperatureRoom1_room' already exists", "code" : 48, "codeName" : "NamespaceExists" }
```

This is my agent.conf file:

```
cygnus-ngsi.sources = http-source
cygnus-ngsi.sinks = mongo-sink
cygnus-ngsi.channels = mongo-channel

cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.channels = mongo-channel
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.port = 5050
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.NGSIRestHandler
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = default
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = /
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.NGSIGroupingInterceptor$Builder
cygnus-ngsi.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /opt/apache-flume/conf/grouping_rules.conf


cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.NGSIMongoSink
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.channel = mongo-channel
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_encoding = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_grouping = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_name_mappings = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_lowercase = false
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.data_model = dm-by-entity
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.attr_persistence = row
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_hosts = iot-mongo:27017
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_username =
cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_password =
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.db_prefix = sth_
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.collection_prefix = sth_
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.batch_size = 1
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.batch_timeout = 30
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.batch_ttl = 10
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.data_expiration = 0
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.collections_size = 0
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.max_documents = 0
#cygnus-ngsi.sinks.mongo-sink.ignore_white_spaces = true

cygnus-ngsi.channels.mongo-channel.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.channels.CygnusMemoryChannel
cygnus-ngsi.channels.mongo-channel.capacity = 1000
cygnus-ngsi.channels.mongo-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

Am I doing something wrong? Can someone help with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about you explain what you've tried? It's best to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: In Orion I created a subscription that shall send a notification to Cygnus whenever the value for temperature changes. Although Cygnus is able to save the data into MySQL, it can not save it to MongoDB because of the problem I tried to explain above. The problem simply is that Cygnus always wants to create a new collection in MongoDB instead of adding a new document to it.

Answer (score 0):

Cygnus always try to create the collection upon notification reception, before inserting the data. Why? Because asking MongoDB for collection existence plus asking MongoDB for collection creation only when the collection does not exist are two operations through the driver; while asking MongoDB for always creating the collection is just one operation. Thus, if the collection exists, it should be OK if you see a DEBUG log trace telling you the collection exists. (*)

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/cygnus-ngsi/src/main/java/com/telefonica/iot/cygnus/sinks/NGSIMongoSink.java#L364

```
try {
   backend.createDatabase(dbName);
   backend.createCollection(dbName, collectionName, collectionsSize, maxDocuments, dataExpiration);
   backend.insertContextDataRaw(dbName, collectionName, aggregation);
} catch (Exception e) {
   throw new CygnusPersistenceError("-, " + e.getMessage());
} // try catch
```

The problem is you are experiencing a WARN log trace, which is bad. What version of MongoDB are you using? Reviewing the code, it could be a problem when interpreting MongoDB responses upon collection creation, which is not based in the error code but in the message string: if you MongoDB returns a different message than expected, an error is raised. This is must be improved, for sure.

https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/cygnus-common/src/main/java/com/telefonica/iot/cygnus/backends/mongo/MongoBackendImpl.java#L106

```
// create the collection
try {
   db.createCollection(collectionName);
} catch (Exception e) {
   if (e.getMessage().contains("collection already exists")) {
      LOGGER.debug("Collection already exists, nothing to create");
   } else {
      throw e;
   } // if else
} // try catch
```

(*) This could be improved by using a "cache" of already created databases and collections. Such a cache would save lot of operations through the MongoDB driver.  This idea has already been implemented for CKAN and MySQL sinks.

Comment: The issue commented in this answer was finally fixed in https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/issues/1377